# Find arraylist index using integer value

Tags: java, arraylist

I have been tasked to remove a arraylist index by using a employeeId.

Here is the code I have, but I have no idea how to find the index. 
Is there a better way to do this?

```
private void addButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    employee workPerson;
    int employeeId = Integer.parseInt(employeeField.getText());
    String firstName = firstField.getText();
    String lastName = lastField.getText();
    int annualSalary = Integer.parseInt(salaryField.getText());
    workPerson = new employee(employeeId,firstName,lastName,"g",annualSalary);
    employeeList.add(workPerson);
}

class employee {
    int annualSalary,employeeId;
    String firstName, lastName,startDate;

    employee (int _employeeId,String _firstName, String _lastName, String _startDate,int _annualSalary) {
       employeeId = _employeeId;
       firstName = _firstName;
       lastName = _lastName;
       startDate = _startDate;
       annualSalary = _annualSalary;
    }
}
```

Comment: The index of the `workPerson` you added in `addButtonActionPerformed`? Is that what you're asking for? If so, it's `employeeList.size() - 1`

Comment: That's true only when you're adding, (which could be the case since the code is within addButtonActionPerformed). 
But in general, the solution I suggested is better (IMHO).

Answer (score 0):

```
private int getEmployeeIndexByEmployeeId(List<employee> list, int desiredId) {
    for (employee employee : list) {
        if (employee.employeeId == desiredId)
            return list.indexOf(employee);
    }
}
```

and then in you code use:

```
    int employeeIndex = getEmployeeIndexByEmployeeId(list, desiredId);
    list.remove(employeeIndex);
```

That should return the index of the desired employeeId.
Make sure you understand the logic here and don't just copy-paste